# Is it possible to mark a property as indexed=false with JDO in Java on the Google Appengine Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use indexed=false in JDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601492/how-to-use-indexed-false-in-jdo)

Answers to this question [Too Many Write Ops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683035/too-many-write-ops) say that it is possible to mark a property to not be indexed. Is it possible to do the same thing in Java with JDO?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601492/how-to-use-indexed-false-in-jdo seems to answer it. Need to search better.